# remove orphan tab order in qt-designer?

Tags: python-3.x, qt4, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have a multiple widget in my form, I deleted some widget but their tab orders not removed and gui not run.
something like this :

```
MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_FID, MainWindow.lineEdit_124)
AttributeError: 'FGui' object has no attribute 'lineEdit_124'
```

I design my gui with qt-designer,
How to can i remove orphan tab order from my gui in qt-designer?

qt4.8
py3
qt-designer 4.8.4

Comment: Funny solution! I see .ui code and not exist any orphan tab order in it, Then I close and reopen qt-designer and Problem solved!! I think problem is qt-designer cache or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny solution!
I see .ui code and not exist any orphan tab order in it, Then
I close and reopen qt-designer and Problem solved!!
I think problem is qt-designer cache or something like that.